# How to process only one message of given type at a time?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messaging, amqp

I have multiple producers which produce requests for processing components. There are lots of those components and processing of each one of them takes significant time.

The problem is that there can be at most one processing task per component running an a time. In other words, no two tasks can operate simultaneously on one component, but different components can (and should) be processed in parallel.

My idea wast to create separate queue for each component and have all workers subscribe to all of those queues. Message broker would emit only one message from any queue and wait for ACK. This way I'll be sure that multiple components can be processed simultaneously, but only one processing task for given component would take place.

My question is: is it possible? And if yes – is it a good approach at all? Maybe there is another solution for that problem?

Here is a diagram of my approach:

```
+----------+              +-------------+
| producer | -----------> |  Exchange   |
+----------+              +-------------+
                           |     |     |
                           v     v     v
                          +-+   +-+   +-+
                          |-|   |-|   |-|
                          |-|   |-|   |-|  Queues per component
                          |-|   |-|   |-|
                          +-+   +-+   +-+
                           |     |     |
                           +-----+-----+
                          /             \
                         v               v
                  +------------+   +------------+
                  | Consumer 1 |   | Consumer 2 |
                  +------------+   +------------+
```

**Edit** — Could it be solved with just one queue? The idea with separate queues per component sounds good until number of components (basically unbounded) is considered.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (and a good idea, IMO) to use a queue per component. I don't think it would work well for one queue (your edited question).

The devil is in the details, and those depend on what queueing system you use.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking of components as queues, think of them as topics. When a worker wants to listen for particular components, it can create an exclusive queue that is bound to your topic exchange based on the topic (which would be the component name or other unique id).

You'll have to be aware that messages published to a topic with no consumers will be dropped, so take that into account via the `mandatory` flag or use an [Alternate Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html)